# Turn off condition check when condition is met?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

Can checking for a condition be turned off when that condition is met and how would this be implemented (using language of your choosing)?

Example:

Say an if-statement runs inside an update function, I would like this if-statement not to be called when the statement has run true once in the lifecycle of the program. I'm thinking this might be achieved by wrapping the statement in a function variable(javascript) then reassigning that variable to return void if/when the condition is true.

Comment: Simply run out of the condition scope, like a `break` in `while`???

Comment: If you mean strictly *if* (but not *only if*), then this can be done by simply removing the code that checks for the condition. If you mean *if and only if*, then it is not possible, as to decide whether or not to check the condition, you would first have to check the condition, at which point it would be too late to not check the condition.

Comment: can you be more clear pls? Try and give an example of the behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your input. @bolov say an if-statement runs inside an update function, I would like this if-statement not to be called when the statement has run true once in the lifecycle of the program. I'm thinking this might be achieved by wrapping the statement in a function variable(javascript) then reassigning that variable to return void if/when the condition is true.

Comment: Or Use Do While or While loop so if the condition are met the statement will now be terminated...

Comment: @GoroundoVipa A while loop would not exactly work in the way I would like as a while loop will just loop until a break/condition is not met. I need other things to happen between each loop. I cannot stick everything in the loop and other things need to run regardless of the condition.

Comment: If your using a language that is available using Multi Threading it will be suit to your Logic to execute multiple process in synchonous process...

Answer (score 0):

Ok let’s say you have this (C++):

```cpp
void update() {
  // code

  if (condition) {
    // code
  }  

  // code
}
```

What you can do is:

```cpp
void update() {
  // code

  static bool already_ran = false;
  if (!already_ran && condition) {
    alreadu_ran = true;
    // code
  }  

  // code
}
```

`static` means that the variable retains it's value over function calls and in C/C++ the logical operators (`&&` in this example) are short-circuited. That means that they don’t evaluate the second operand unless they need. For instance if `!already_ran` is `false` then the whole expression is `false` regardless of `condition` so `condition` is not evaluated.

Comment: A condition is still being evaluated. I was hoping there would be some native language functionality or design pattern to avoid this all together. Reason being I think it would be more efficient than running an arbitrary number of conditions (even Boolean, could be in the 1000's) on every call to update() (e.g. 30 times a second).

Comment: Ha I'm sure it is still very fast :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is more efficient than using a simple condition to run the increaseValue() function but here is the code I am using and it seems to work (in as3 at least). Update is being called approx 30 times a second.

```
public function update(){
    if(isHit){ //isHit is part of another condition used by collision
        increaseValues = function() {
            this.height += 1;
            this.width += 1;
            this.x -= 1;
            this.y -= 1;
            this.alpha += -0.1;
            if (this.alpha == 0){
                increaseValues = function(){
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    increaseValues();
}
```